# Capture all messages between members in a channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

The goal is to save all the dialog between one channel members (e.g. MS Teams) and then send it to another channel.

Is that possible to capture all messages between channel members by sideloaded bot or something?

I used that code from documentation:

```
const logUserConversation = (event) => {
    console.log('message: ' + event.text + ', user: ' + event.address.user.name);
};

// Middleware for logging
bot.use({
    receive: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation(event);
        next();
    },
    send: function (event, next) {
        logUserConversation(event);
        next();
    }
});
```

But it triggers only if you directly @mentioning the bot, no action if conversation going on between the channel members.
I suspect that it could be the security policy of the bot framework and it is not possible at all...

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: Ok, a support member said to me that the ability to do so is on the roadmap, it will be available later with Graph API.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that's possible at all. You can log the messages between users and the bot; but not the messages between users even if the bot is in the channel where the conversation is happening.

Comment: Correct. Microsoft Teams does not yet support the ability to follow a channel or the correspondence between a set of users. Bots can only see messages in which they are explicitly @mentioned.

The ability to do so is on the roadmap, but we need to do it in such a way that it respects enterprise data security requirements consistent with the rest of Office 365.

We will be adding the ability to read a channel's contents via the Microsoft Graph APIs but that capability is not yet available.

Comment: Thank you @BillBliss-MSFT! You just confirmed what support member said to me. This feature is vital for us, because we plan to analyze and use channel conversation info for bot learning later.